# Convert TextBox text to type

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I want to create a textbox control similar to the one existing in Workflow variables grid.

for exemple if i'm typing a string i must write something like that: **"*str*"**
if i'm typing an integer value i write directly 1... for example.

how can i do it so the output of my control be an object, if i enter a number so the output will be of type integer, or if i enter a date time the output will be a DateTime.

Should i have to parse it manually or there is an existing thing that i can use.

Comment: does [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter(v=vs.95).aspx) help?

Comment: Do you only need string and integer? Do you need support for other system types? do you need support for User defined types?

Comment: What is the complete range of types you need to support?  For example do you need to support byte, short int, int, long  OR would int be sufficient?  Similarly float, double or would just double do?  Do you need DateTime, if so what syntax would you like to use to represent it as a literal string (e.g.; #20111011#)?

Comment: For now i want to support all native types. but next stage i want to support user defined types.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Regular Expression (Regex)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

With regex you can check if a String consists of Numbers, is formatted like a Date or whatever you want to check.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the [ExpressionTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.view.expressiontextbox.aspx) control? It doesn't know the type beforehand, you still have to set its ExpressionType property, for it to validate its input.

Do you want the control to automatically recognize what type of input it is? Then I would also suggest using regular expressions, but I think it might become a bit complex for even the simplest user defined types. Then you would have to explain how the syntax should be for those types, and that's kinda working against why you're making this control in the first place.

PS. I don't have a suggestion for an answer, so I would have written this as a comment instead, but I don't have enough rep.